# SQL Server Reporting Service(SSRS) 2005 reports on SSRS 2008

Tags: report, ssrs-2008, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I have reports created using Visual Studio 2005 targeted to SSRS 2005.

If I want to open these reports using SSRS 2008, can I just deploy SSRS 2005 reports on SSRS 2008?

Is SSRS 2008 fully compatible with SSRS 2005 reports?

Please revise these following steps, if I'm doing something wrong:

```
1. Open SSRS 2005 reports on Visual Studio 2005
2. Change the deployment TargetServerURL to SSRS 2008.
3. Deploy
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SSRS 2008 is fully compatible with SSRS 2005 reports.  From my understanding upgrading is a one way trip however.  Once it's been upgraded it will no longer run in a 2005 instance.  So, keep a backup copy handy if for some reason you need to go back.

As for the proper procedure to upgrade from 2005 to 2008 Microsoft has written a very thorough guide here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143674(v=sql.100).aspx

Comment: SSRS 2008 changed how page breaks are handled.  Some formatting that worked in 2005 becomes "Error" in 2008.  Nothing major, but if someone is checking 2005 to 2008 and demanding perfection, they'll drive themselves crazy.